# uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int error

Tags: stored-procedures

This is my Select statement in my stored procedure, i am trying to get all cases based on just the begin date as entered by the user. I keep getting ' uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int'. Not sure how to go about that.

```
(
            SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT C.CaseID)
            FROM [Case] C
            INNER JOIN CaseOffice COD ON C.CaseId = COD.CaseId
            INNER JOIN Office OD ON COD.OfficeId = OD.OfficeId
            WHERE C.DateCreated <= @BeginDate AND  OD.OfficeId = O.OfficeId
            AND C.CaseId NOT IN
            (
                SELECT CaseId 
                FROM CaseStatusChange CSC
                WHERE CSC.DateClosed < @BeginDate
            )
            UNION
            SELECT ReOpened.CaseId FROM
            (
                SELECT C.CaseId, MAX(CSC.DateReopened) AS DateReOpened 
                FROM [Case] C 
                INNER JOIN [CaseStatusChange] CSC ON C.CaseId = CSC.CaseId
                WHERE CSC.DateReopened <= @BeginDate
                GROUP BY C.CaseId
            ) ReOpened 
            WHERE ReOpened.CaseId NOT IN -- Wasn't reopened and closed 
            (
                SELECT CaseId FROM CaseStatusChange 
                WHERE CaseId = ReOpened.CaseId AND 
                CaseStatusChange.DateClosed BETWEEN ReOpened.DateReopened AND @BeginDate
            )
        )AS OpenBeginCases
```

Answer (score 0):

CaseID is uniqueidentifier and you UNION this with COUNT(DISTINCT C.CaseID) which will be int

```
...
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT C.CaseID) --int
...
UNION
...
SELECT ReOpened.CaseId --uniqueidentifier 
...
```

So this error would be expected. Do you need the COUNT in the first clause?

Comment: i want to count how many open cases there are based on the begin date. I removed the union and just left it as the first count clause and executed it but all my returns for the column was 0.

Comment: You asked about an error: I told you why it happened. A count of zero means your query is wrong which is a *different* question: it works, no error, just wrong data.